# How to package several dylibs as a single OS-X Framework using Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, boost

I am trying to package a set of google boost libraries together as an OS-X private framework, and fail miserably.

I succeeded in using boosts build-tools on the Mac (b2, bjam) to build both static lib (.a) and dynamic lib (.dylib) versions of the boost libraries I need.

I created in Xcode a framework target (configured as a private framework). I linked it against the 7 dylibs I need, and I managed to copy the Headers into place, and copy the actual dylibs into the framework's executables directory, so that they will be brought together with the new "boost" framework.

However, the "top" dynamic library of the framework - (named "boost" on diet) does not export any of the symbols in those 7 libraries.

So I can build my framework - but not use it.

I found an attempt to automatically (using script) create an iOS "framework" (with internal static lib) from boost, but this script is old and doesn't work on later boost versions, and also - it is not an Xcode project, just a script.

I tried to find how to re-export the symbols of linked .dylibs through my "boost" dynamic lib, but could not understand how.

Ideas anyone?
I'm really frustrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not without sweat and tears, I finally got it to work, and here are the tricks involved.
After doing all the things I mentioned in the original question, you must also:

1. In the build-settings, find "Re-Exported Library Names", and add the dylibs, named like thus: `boost_iostreams boost_locale boost_regex boost_signals boost_system boost_thread boost_filesystem` (this took a day - why you need to drop the "lib" and the ".dylib" and what it means to re-export a dylib).
2. In the build-phases, add a run-script phase before Compilation, (you can name it `Run Script - Fix boost dylibs`, and add the following script (might need changes depending where you placed your boost build dir)

```sh
#!/bin/bash  

src_boost_dylib_dir=$SRCROOT/../../../boost_1_59_0_lib/dylib

dest_boost_dylib_dir=$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/$EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH

boost_dylibs=( libboost_filesystem.dylib libboost_iostreams.dylib  libboost_locale.dylib libboost_regex.dylib libboost_signals.dylib  libboost_system.dylib libboost_thread.dylib)

for bdl in "${boost_dylibs[@]}"; do  
    echo Fixing boost dylib:$bdl
    # at runtime, 'boost' loads its re-exported dylibs for other clients (such as AP) linked to boost. To find them, it must look in the same directory where boost is.
    install_name_tool -id @loader_path/$bdl $src_boost_dylib_dir/$bdl
    # make all dependent boost dylibs also relative to @loader_path, so that they can find each other in runtime.

    dependencies=`otool -L $src_boost_dylib_dir/$bdl | grep  "^\slibboost_" | awk -F' ' '{ print $1 }'`
    for dependency_dylib in "${dependencies[@]}"; do
        if [ "${dependency_dylib}" == "" ]; then
            continue
        fi
        echo Dependency:$dependency_dylib
        install_name_tool -change $dependency_dylib  @loader_path/$dependency_dylib $src_boost_dylib_dir/$bdl

    done
done
```

3. As in the Question, add a copy-files build-phase, after Linkage phase, to copy the dylibs into the "Executables" directory, so they reside with the built product (boost dylib).
4. After that phase, copy another run-script phase, called `Run Script - Create symlink to reexported dylibs`. Add the following script:

```
# Create symlinks for all re-exported dylibs, at the framework's top level. They must be also relative to the framework directory.
cd $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/$WRAPPER_NAME
ln -Ffsv Versions/Current/libboost_*.dylib .
```

You should be done.

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated. You can try, if this build script brings you closer to a solution:

https://gist.github.com/JanX2/80721c30192e64ed124e

Comment: I looked at the build-script there --- and you call MY solution "complicated"??? Besides, these scripts create a monolith behemoth, of huge binary size, that can only be loaded to memory in one chunk, whereas my multiple-dylib re-packaging provides both better resolution in selecting the parts of Boost you need, and in loading these parts only when needed.

Comment: If you look at the dates you will find that my suggestion was posted prior to yours. I was not commenting on your solution, but on the issue itself. :)

Comment: Oh, sorry... Sometimes one needs to actually look at dates properly :) but now I can adhere completely -- it IS complicated. and although I made it - it took a lot of time. (and pre-build of boost dylibs in advance).